# Delayed scroll to Div ID when select option is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, delay

I'd like to be able to scroll to a particular ID when a select option has been chosen from a drop down list. It seems like it should be extremely simple, however I can't find an example on here that performs how I want it to.

Basically, I have a div near the top of the page

`<div id="mainimage">CONTENT</div>`

Then lower down the page, a select box:

```
<select id="variant">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to do, is - once a selection has been made - for the page to scroll back up to the id "mainimage".

If possible, ideally this would happen after a delay of around half a second, and scroll smoothly.

It seems like it should be fairly straightforward, as the page just needs to scroll to the same ID regardless of the selection.

Is this possible with javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. I have used a jquery inside a javascript function. Hope it helps

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("test").value;
  document.getElementById("mainimage").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
   setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#mainimage").offset().top
  }, 2000);
 },500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="mainimage">welcm to mainimage </p>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
<!-- M using br tags since i dont have content to be placed here .. since to see scrolling we need some content to be here to fill up the page -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<select id="test" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#variant').on('change',function(){
 setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#mainimage").offset().top
  }, 2000);
 },500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

I added CSS scroll smooth, also you can change JS it's only to see the dynamics.

```js
document.getElementById("select").onchange = function(){
  if(this.selectedIndex == 0){
     window.location.hash = '#section1';
  } else {
    window.location.hash = '#section2';
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
* {
margin-bottom: 300px;
}
#section1 {
height: 500px;
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

#section2 {
height: 500px;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<select id="select" name="sections">
  <option>Section 1</option>
  <option>Section 2</option>
</select>

<div id="section1">
Section 1
</div>

<div id="section2">
Section 2
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I just needed it to delay before firing.